# Build a button that displays the number of times it has been clicked in WORDPRESS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, button, build

Here is my problem: I want to build/program a button that displays the number of times it has been clicked by some visitor on my website.

Basically it is a simple counter. My problem is that I use Wordpress and I don't know how to build it and then integrate it inside Wordpress.

I have tried literally 15 plugins none of them suits this basic requirement. The few that does, don't allow me to set the initial number and I need to be able to do that.

I tried embedding some code in a text block/html block directly inside the page, but it didn't gave me anything. Wordpress doesn't interpret the code correctly or not at all.

So even if I manage to build/program a simple counter in php (which is a langage I do not know but building something as simple as a counter should not be difficult) I do not know how to put it and make it usable in Wordpress. So that is my biggest issue.

If you could help me, it would be great!

Many thanks!

EDIT: It was kindly requested that I add some informations about the button functionality so here it is:

The button would be displayed in a banner at the top of each page.
Any visitor should be able to click on it.
At every click it will increment by one and display the new count.
The page should not refresh, only the counter should be updated instantly.
The value of the counter has to be stored. So that whenever a visitor comes, he will see the current count and could himself click on it to increment it.
The visitor should be able to click on it only once.

I have tried this:
https://www.dougv.com/2008/12/a-simple-page-click-count-system-using-php-and-mysql/

Unfortunately, when I put the code in a custom html block on wordpress it doesn't work. And I don't know in which folder to put it and how to call it in Wordpress.

Comment: When you click on the button, does it refresh the page? Is the counter unique per user or for everyone on your site? What does the button do? Be more specific please.

Comment: @bugfroggy Thank you for your comment. I have updated the post, I hope it is clear now.

Comment: When you say `I tried embedding some code in a text block/html block directly inside the page.` are you adding the html to a php file or are you adding it inside of WordPress's editor?

Comment: Inside Wordpress editor

Answer (score 1):

Easy Way to do this is to create a table in your main database Like in the tutorial you put.

```
CREATE TABLE click_count (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   page_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   page_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
);
```

now whenever someone clicks the link post the values to say update_count.php file using ajax. In update_count.php will start with these lines

```
<?php

$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
    global $wpdb;
```

Adding this will give you access to wp functions . Now update the database using the $wpdp variable you can find the Codex here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
. Now after updating return success and update the count in frontend using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But where do I put the php code. The creation of MySQL is ok. And I understand the php code but I do not now where to put it in wordpress and how to refer to it ?

Comment: u can create a file named update_count.php  in either ur theme folder or in the root directory . its good u put in theme directory and call that file in your ajax call.

Comment: I'll try this ! Thanks!

Comment: Ok.. Dont forget to make this as answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution to this is this:
1.Connect and register a handler for click event on that button.
2.This handler javascript function will, in turn, call ajax for a PHP page.
3.This PHP page that you will also have to write will then +1 a field in the database.
4.Voila.

-It is best to do each of the steps yourself, because it is the best way to learn. I will try and help you out more if you want, and if you are interested in more details, upvote my answer. So then I will elaborate and provide you with more code on this.

Comment: Hello Vladimir, thank you for your answer. My main problem is how to implement the code in Wordpress. I have found some code for the counter. But when I try to put it in wordpress it doesn't work.

Comment: @PainAndGain did you find any answer to your problem with implementation of code to WordPress?